# Python C Extension - How to map a Python string to a C Macro Constant?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

I'm wrapping a legacy C library. There are a few header files that contains thousands of macro constants like:

```
#define FOO 1
#define BAR 2
#define BAZ 3
```

I would like for the user in Python to be able to specify the string `"FOO"`, which will then be executed in the wrapped C function as `1`, for example `mycmod.wrapped_function("FOO")`.

Currently, my library is parsing these header files in python at start up time, and creates a dict like:

```
values = {"FOO": 1, "BAR": 2, "BAZ": 3}
```

This way, in python the user can:

```
mycmod.wrapped_function(values['FOO'])
```

Which calls a wrapped C function.

It's not that great because I have to make the parser of the header file ignore comments, and I also have to hard code all the header files that I want to parse into the Python library; if someone adds a new header file they have to remember to add it to the parser.

Is there a better way to allow the user to specify a string in Python that can somehow map to a macro defined constant in C?

Comment: I don't see how else to solve it other than to parse the headers, but if the library's include directory is fixed and known, then you could use `glob.glob` to find all `*.h` files rather than hard-coding their file names. Also, the answer provided here (about pyparsing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17182629/find-all-macro-definition-in-c-header-file may be of help